# Full height fixed sidebar with scrolling sections

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a fixed side bar navigation with collapsible sections. I have a lot of menu items, and I don't want the entire sidebar to scroll when there isn't enough space height wise (as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/a7yt009d/)), rather I'm trying to set each collapsible section to `overflow:auto` so that they will scroll independently.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/c6r9w5qc/) shows the concept, but it limits each section to 200px - what I want is for it *not* to scroll if the space available.

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.nav_wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 250px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav_panel {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <div class="nav_sidebar">
      <!--start menu item 1-->
      <div class="nav_menuItem" data-toggle="collapsed">
          <div class="nav_label">
              Menu Label 1
          </div>
          <div class="nav_panel">
              <ul>
                  <li>Item One</li>
                   ...
              </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried adding `height: 100%` on `.nav_panel' like so:

```
.nav_panel {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But this causes the section to have height greater than 100% of it's parent.

I've seen this achieved using flex boxes (see example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/tristen/f11ada26c2a696b1bf801949d876a7a3)) but I need support for IE9 - is there some way other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you just increase the `max-height`?

Comment: I guess I may not be explaining it well - yes I could increase the max height, but what I'm trying to achieve is for the height to be fluid in resizing so that it doesn't get cut off when the screen is smaller